# iOS 4.3 - Network connection lost when attempting web service connection?

Tags: web-services, http, authentication, ios4

I am working on some code to connect to a secured .NET based web service. I have tried to connect using a manually created SOAP messsage, HTTP POST and HTTP GET. In each try, I am using NSMutableURLRequest on a NSURLConnection. I have implemented didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge in the following manner...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"Authentication challenge");

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"authentication failed");

        NSURLCredential *credential ;

        credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

        NSLog(@"credential created");

        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        NSLog(@"credential sent");
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Credentials are wrong!");

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

All log messages appear. About 30 seconds after "credential sent" is written, I get the following error.

> Connection failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

I've found numerous examples here and elsewhere on handling the authentication challenge. Nothing I'm doing seems to be out of the ordinary. I also implemented the following just in case but the results are the same.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
    NSLog(@"canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");

    //return YES to say that we have the necessary credentials to access the requested    resource
    return YES;
}
```

The username/password I am sending in response to the challenge exist. I have verified by entering the service URL in a browser and entering the username/password in the authentication dialog. XML is returned when invoking the service through the browser.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a couple of days now. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: I just tried making the connection without didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge by just commenting it out and just placing the username/password in the URL, 'http://user:password@server/path/to/service'. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: I am also having the same problem, Sean have u solved your problem, if yes then please help me to solve this problem. as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I just found my error. The URL wasn't being encoded properly, but I didn't realize that until I had dug a bit into `NSUrl URLWithString:`. I added the following code and all is well.

```
NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server/path/to/service.asmx/Method?param=%@", param.text];

NSString *fixedURL = [myURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:fixedURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 4.3.1 (just released!) has this in the release notes:

**Resolves bugs related to activating and connecting to some cellular networks**

Maybe it also addresses your issue. I have similar effects using SOAP under MonoTouch on the iPad. When switching to 3G it claims that it cannot connect (Socket error). I will also try if updating helps.

Comment: I am not running on a device. This is all in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

No not yet. I'm thinking I may have to write a separate service to handle the authentication that sits between the iPad and the service that has the data I need. The iPad won't do any authentication. Not the ideal solution but it'd work for the time being.

Comment: Was this supposed to be a comment?